# Create a promise object with N-API native addons

Tags: node.js, node.js-addon

I am looking for node.js native example code for creating a **promise object** from **C** (or C++) either by **N-API** (or node-addon-api) that can be used from node.js JavaScript layer. (More precisely the usage will be with **async/await** keyword). Any help on this highly appreciated.  The following github repository was helpful, unfortunately I could not find an example for the one I am looking for.
https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-examples
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what you're trying to accomplish (e.g., creating a promise that will be resolved in JavaScript or creating a promise that the C++ code will resolve) it's hard to answer specifically.

But this doc probably has the information you need to make progress.

https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-api/blob/master/doc/promises.md

Comment: Thank for the information, this will be helpful, I will dig more detail into it. By the way, plan to get the promise resolved at native layer.